# Flume 1.7 & Kafka - How to restart at the beginning of the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I'm using a Flume 1.7 Kafka `source` to pull data out of Apache Kafka into my `AbstractSink`. In the past I could re-start the offsets at the beginning of the topic by deleting the topic offsets using `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --delete` but since Flume 1.7 (apparently) uses a "new" consumer, attempting `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --delete` now gives the following error message:

> Option [delete] is not valid with [new-consumer]. Note that there's no
>   need to delete group metadata for the new consumer as it is
>   automatically deleted when the last member leaves

So, what is the recommended method of achieving the desired behavior (which is that we will re-process the data from the beginning of the topic) ?

Here is part of my flume config:

```
myagent.sources.my-kafka-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
myagent.sources.my-kafka-source.kafka.bootstrap.servers = kafka.example.net:9092
myagent.sources.my-kafka-source.kafka.consumer.group.id = my-gid
myagent.sources.my-kafka-source.kafka.topics = my.topic
myagent.sources.my-kafka-source.kafka.auto.offset.reset = earliest
myagent.sources.my-kafka-source.channels = my_channel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flume does not offer direct support to the rewind feature although kafka does ships with KafkaConsumer#seek allowing you to re-consume the messages. Seems you have to use a new group id to do this which needs to restart the Flume agent.